# Memory leak on AppCompatButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, performance-testing, leakcanary

I am working on an App which has LeakCanary integrated. Throughout my app I keep getting LeakCanary notification "App will Freeze, Brrr...". Now If a leak is consistent it can not be ignored. So I went through the logs and found below.

```
├─ com.ilumi.fragments.ListFragment
│    Leaking: YES (Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
│    ↓ ListFragment.mAddToList
├─ com.ilumi.widgets.CenteredLeftDrawableButton
│    Leaking: YES (ListFragment↑ is leaking and View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    mContext instance of com.ilumi.activities.DetailActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ CenteredLeftDrawableButton.mContext
╰→ com.ilumi.activities.DetailActivity
 ​     Leaking: YES (CenteredLeftDrawableButton↑ is leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is true and
```

Now from the looks of it, I figured the issue is withing the CenteredLeftDrawableButton which I have used at many places in my app.

```
public class CenteredLeftDrawableButton extends AppCompatButton {

    public CenteredLeftDrawableButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CenteredLeftDrawableButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CenteredLeftDrawableButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablePadding(int pad) {
        super.setCompoundDrawablePadding(pad);
        centerDrawables();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
        centerDrawables();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int start, int top, int end, int bottom) {
        super.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(start, top, end, bottom);
        centerDrawables();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable start, Drawable top, Drawable end, Drawable bottom) {
        super.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(start, top, end, bottom);
        centerDrawables();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        super.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        centerDrawables();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        centerDrawables();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesRelative(Drawable start, Drawable top, Drawable end, Drawable bottom) {
        super.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(start, top, end, bottom);
        centerDrawables();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        centerDrawables();
    }

    private void centerDrawables() {
        Drawable[] compoundDrawables = getCompoundDrawables();
        Drawable drawableLeft = compoundDrawables[0];
        Drawable drawableRight = compoundDrawables[2];
        if (drawableLeft != null || drawableRight != null) {
            float textWidth = getPaint().measureText(getText().toString());
            int drawablePadding = getCompoundDrawablePadding();
            int drawableWidth = 0;
            if (drawableLeft != null) {
                drawableWidth += drawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth();
            }
            if (drawableRight != null) {
                drawableWidth += drawableRight.getIntrinsicWidth();
            }
            float bodyWidth = textWidth + drawableWidth + drawablePadding;
            if (bodyWidth < getWidth()) {
                float emptySpace = getWidth() - bodyWidth;
                int paddingToLeftAndRight = (int) (emptySpace / 2);
                setPadding(paddingToLeftAndRight, getPaddingTop(), paddingToLeftAndRight, getPaddingBottom());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void centerDrawables(TextView view) {
        Drawable[] compoundDrawables = view.getCompoundDrawables();
        Drawable drawableLeft = compoundDrawables[0];
        Drawable drawableRight = compoundDrawables[2];
        if (drawableLeft != null || drawableRight != null) {
            float textWidth = view.getPaint().measureText(view.getText().toString());
            int drawablePadding = view.getCompoundDrawablePadding();
            int drawableWidth = 0;
            if (drawableLeft != null) {
                drawableWidth += drawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth();
            }
            if (drawableRight != null) {
                drawableWidth += drawableRight.getIntrinsicWidth();
            }
            float bodyWidth = textWidth + drawableWidth + drawablePadding;
            if (bodyWidth < view.getWidth()) {
                float emptySpace = view.getWidth() - bodyWidth;
                int paddingToLeftAndRight = (int) (emptySpace / 2);
                view.setPadding(paddingToLeftAndRight, view.getPaddingTop(), paddingToLeftAndRight, view.getPaddingBottom());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I every class below are the uses of the button that I am doing.

```
      private CenteredLeftDrawableButton mAddToSchedule;


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAddToSchedule = (CenteredLeftDrawableButton) view.findViewById(R.id.editScheduleButton);

mAddToSchedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Intent to open new screen
            }
        });
    }

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    if (someConditionTrue) {
                mAddToList.setText(R.string.button_add_to_schedule);
                mAddToList.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp, 0, 0, 0);

    } else {
                mAddToList.setText(R.string.button_update_firmware);
                mAddToList.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

There is nothing heavy happening except for a drawable being added. I am not sure how to fix this. If anyone can help, that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

ListFrament at the top has "Leaking: YES", which means that it should not be held in memory, which means that the problem is before it in the trace. So you'll need to paste the entire trace to get help. Find the references where "Leaking: " goes from "no" to "yes" and you will find the cause. The cause is definitely not with the drawable button.